# What does () => mean in C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

I've been reading through the source code for [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) and I came across the following unit test:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => Times.AtLeast(0));
```

And for the life of me, I can't remember what () => actually does. I'm think it has something to do with anonymous methods or lambdas. And I'm sure I know what it does, I just can't remember at the moment....

And to make matters worse....[google isn't being much help](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=%28%29+%3D%3E&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) and [neither is stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%29+%3D%3E)

Can someone give me a quick answer to a pretty noobish question?

Comment: Remembers me when I was looking for information about "*=" in SQL... not the most search engine friendly operator...

Comment: if I understand this correctly, it means that if Times.AtLeast(0) is false then some exception is thrown. Am I correct? Will this work only on "debug" mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

()=> is  a nullary lambda expression. it represents an anonymous function that's passed to assert.Throws, and is called somewhere inside of that function.

```
void DoThisTwice(Action a) { 
    a();
    a();
}
Action printHello = () => Console.Write("Hello ");
DoThisTwice(printHello);

// prints "Hello Hello "
```

Comment: So then, essentially, the unit test code is creating an anonymous method that calls a method that is then executed by the Throws method which handles the exception thrown and asserts that the correct exception was thrown?

Answer (score 13):

Search StackOverflow for "lambda".

Specifically:

```
() => Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
```

That means "a method that takes no arguments and returns void, and when you call it, it writes the message to the console."

You can store it in an Action variable:

```
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
```

And then you can call it:

```
a();
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but probably because "Search Stack Overflow for lambda" isn't very helpful considering the OP acknowledged that he knew it has something to do with lambdas. +1 from me, though.

Comment: Someone probably downvoted it before you expanded on your initial answer. Looking at your answer now, though, it is definitely very helpful.

Comment: @Earwicker: Like you don't have enough rep. :P

Comment: for some reason I thought that you weren't allowed to vote-grub in questions you've answered in.... where did I get that idea from :P

Comment: I downvoted it at first. "You have to search this and this" is not a helpful answer. If you also give a link to the search and the most important results, I consider it helpful. And now of course, so my downvote flipped.

Answer (score 9):

It's a lambda expression. The most common syntax is using a parameter, so there are no parentheses needed around it:

```
n => Times.AtLeast(n)
```

If the number of parameters is something other than one, parentheses are needed:

```
(n, m) => Times.AtLeast(n + m)
```

When there are zero parameters, you get the somewhat awkward syntax with the parentheses around the empty parameter list:

```
() => Times.AtLeast(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
() => Times.AtLeast(0)
```

() indicates that the lambda function has no parameters or return value.

=> indicates that a block of code is to follow.

Times.AtLeast(0) calls the Times class's static method AtLeast with a parameter of 0.

Answer (score 2):

That's the definition of a lambda (anonymous) function. Essentially, it's a way to define a function inline, since Assert.Throws takes a function as an argument and attempts to run it (and then verify that it throws a certain exception).

Essentially, the snippet you have there is a unit test that makes sure Times.AtLeast(0) throws a ArgumentOutOfRangeException. The lambda function is necessary (instead of just trying to call the Times.AtLeast function directly from Assert.Throws) in order to pass the proper argument for the test - in this case 0.

MSDN KB article on the topic here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in C#, but Googling "C# Lambda" provided [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that answers your question!!!