# What does this mean in C# or LINQ? - ( () => )

Tags: c#, linq

I was going through Jeffrey Palermo's book and came across this syntax.

```
private void InitializeRepositories()
{
    Func<IVisitorRepository> builder =  () => new VisitorRepository();
    VisitorRepositoryFactory.RepositoryBuilder = builder;
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: hmm I thought this question smelled familiar....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216004/what-does-mean-in-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`() =>` indicates a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that takes no arguments.

Comment: I like Python's version of lambda better: `builder = lambda: VisitorRepository()`.

Comment: I like javascript's version better: function() VisitorRepository().

Comment: I like Alonzo Church's version of lambda better: λ

Answer (score 4):

In general, it means a function with no arguments.

In this particular example, it creates an anonymous function with no arguments that returns a new `VisitorRepository();` object every time.

Answer (score 2):

`Func<IVisitorRepository>` stands for a delegate which takes no arguments and returns a IVisitorRepository. The creation of that delegate is a lambda function:

```
() //means no parameters
=> new VisitorRepository()// means it returns a new VisitorRepository
```

Answer (score 1):

() is the place where you place your variables

Example a common event handled would look like `(sender, args)`

`=>` // means throw these parameter into this method

after => you can either drop a one line execution thing like `new VisitorRepositor()`

OR

you can place a whole function like

```
Func<IRepository> = (sender, args) => 
{
    var myObject = (SomeObject)sender;
    return new VisitorReposiroty { id = myObject.SomeId };
}
```

As other stated it's lambda expression and it really clears your code from method or function that handle a specific event.

Once you read them good it's really damn useful.

Answer (score 1):

The () => syntax is a lambda expression. Lambdas were introduced in C# 3.0 and are used to define an anonymous method for a delegate.

The delegate is defined using the generic Func. So in this case the signature for the delegate is: no input parameters and one output parameter of type IVisitorRepository.

So on the left side of the => lambda array are the names of the input parameters. In case of no input parameters just write (). On the rightside of the => lambda is the code to return the output parameter, in this example: new VisitorRepository().

I suggest read more about lambda expressions in C# to fully understand this code. There is also a generic delegate involved, so you need understanding of Generics and Delegates as well.

Answer (score 0):

It means a function takes no parameters, like:

```
delegate() {//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Func is a delegate without parmeter and with an IVisitorRepository return value.

() => is a lambda expression creating an anonymous method.

new VisitorRepository() is the content of this anonymous method.

so this line is creating a delegate which is pointing to a anonymous method, which is returning an instance of VisitorRepository.

```
Func<IVisitorRepository> builder =  () => new VisitorRepository()
```

In the next line, you set the value of a static property to this just created delegate.

```
VisitorRepositoryFactory.RepositoryBuilder = builder;
```

After this you can use the property to call the anonymous method, which is creating a new instance of VisitorRepository.

```
IVisitorRepository repository = VisitorRepositoryFactory.RepositoryBuilder();
```

In this case, repository will be an instance of VisitorRepository.