# Lambda syntax looking like this: () =>

Tags: c#, lambda

I came across a lambda syntax, which I cannot trace

```
Action act = () => object.Foo(null);
```

How should this be interpreted? I know how to use lambda expressions, but this one is not clear to me.

Comment: The code does not match your title. In your title you have it backwards.

Comment: What part specifically is not clear to you?

Comment: If you don't think this is a duplicate, please add more explanation of "I know how to use lambda expressions, but this one is not clear to me." - how are *we* meant to know what *aspects* of this are confusing to you versus other examples which you apparently understand just fine.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/3265812/613130, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3627840/613130, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387884/what-does-this-mean-in-c-sharp-or-linq

Answer (score 4):

It's a lambda expression without any parameters. You will use it like this:

```
act();
```

If it had parameters, for example:

```
Action act = x => object.Foo(x);
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
act(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Action act = () => object.Foo(null);
```

is the equivalent to (not the same as)

```
private void act(){ object.Foo(null); }
```

where `act` is method that you call inline instead of defining it in your class.

`Action` is a delegate that does not return a result. There is also a similar type called `Func` which does return a result.

Comment: Not exactly. Apart from the fact you're missing void, whilst they may have the same behavior, they are not fundamentally the same thing. P.S. - wasn't me who down voted.

Comment: @series0ne - i should have used equivalent , better verbage. No, they are not the same, but it does come down that to that Action is a method that can be executed (Delegate). I revised my description.

Comment: I would up vote based on your edit, however act is NOT anonymous... it's called "act"

Comment: Better! all looks okay now.

Comment: Technically, wouldn't the equivalent function body be `return object.Foo(null)`?

Comment: @DavidEtler - no. Action types do not return results (basically a void method). If you wanted to return the result of object.Foo then it would be a Func and specify the return type as a generic.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the info, I was unaware exactly how lambdas work in C#. So whether or not they return something depends on the type of the left hand side? And in this case the LHS is of type Action which returns nothing?

Comment: @DavidEtler - not necessarily. In this case the type Action does not return anything, it has nothing to do with the lamda itself. If you change the code I supplied in the example and leave the private method `act` you could add a line somewhere else in the class code `Action someAction = this.act;' as act is void and Action is a method pointer (delegate) for methods that do not return results. See [Action Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.