# What does ()=> mean(c#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does () => mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216004/what-does-mean-in-c)

Hi Everybody,

This is my first question in stackoverflow.

I have encounter something as

```
() => SomeClass.SomeMethod(param1, param2)
```

This is entirely new to me and I cannot fathom what it is, what we call it, what it does,

how it works etc.

What I am looking for is an explanation for the same with a simple example which can be

understandable easily and I can implement it in my program. It will be nice if I can get

the real time scenario for this implementation.

I am using C#3.0 with dotnet framework 3.5.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the same answer as this guy -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216004/what-does-mean-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lambdas page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) is quite helpful with the syntax.

And yes, `()=>GetSomething()` is an expression lambda that takes no parameters and returns something. The other lambda flavour is a statement lambda, which is an anonymous function that does not return anything - i.e. a `void` function.

Both can take any number of parameters, including none.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda function I guess. It is the kind of function you define "inline".

For example, in LINQ you can do the following:

```
myTable.Where(eleme=>elem.qty>=10);
```

Here you pass the function `leme=>elem.qty>=10` as a parameter to the Where method.

I guess in your example, `() => SomeClass.SomeMethod(param1, param2)` is referring to a function taking no input parameter an returning some value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lambda that creates an Action delegate. 
More info (and example) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

You can also create an action and pass in parameters with `(s) => SomeMethod(s);`

Or, you can pass an entire block:

```
(x) => {
   DoSomething(x);
   if(x.SomeValue == requiredValue){
      x.SomeOtherValue = true;
   }
}
```

For more examples of passing parameters to `Action<T>` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)